# Can't bind to 'mfShowSortableArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'mfDefaultSorter'

Tags: angular, npm

I am working on angular 4 and i have one table which displays some data to sorting and pagination purpose, i have installed '**DataTableModule**' package of angular.

In documentation of this Package ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-data-table)), i found the **mfShowSortableArrows** property for **mfDefaultSorter** control, but when i use it, it throw the error

```
Can't bind to 'mfShowSortableArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'mfDefaultSorter'.
```

As i am imported this package in `app.module.ts`

```
import { DataTableModule } from "ng2-data-table";
-----

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, DataTableModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and used in html as

```
<table [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5" [mfSaveRowsOnPage]="true" (mfSelectedEntities)="setSelectedEntities($event)">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <mfRowSelectorHead></mfRowSelectorHead>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="name" [mfShowSortableArrows]="true">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 50%">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="email">Email</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 10%">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Age</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="city">City</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let ndx = index">
            <td><mfRowSelector [entity]="item" [checkboxId]="ndx"></mfRowSelector></td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            <td>{{item.age}}</td>
            <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

but getting error,

```
Can't bind to 'mfShowSortableArrows' since it isn't a known property of 'mfDefaultSorter'.
```

Comment: From docs: *"An app reference to font-awesome is required if you set 'mfDefaultSorter' component input option 'mfShowSortableArrows' to true."*

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i have added link to css <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">  in html page, but still same error